# How to validate parameters in a functional way?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm writing Scala/Play 2.0 application, and I want my code to return different page depending on request. Here is my code:

```
// Validate client and return temporary credentials
def requestToken = Action { request =>
  // Authorization header may present or not
  val authHeader = parseHeaders(request headers AUTHORIZATION)
  // Authorization header may contain such keys or not
  val clientKey = authHeader("oauth_consumer_key")
  val signature = authHeader("oauth_signature")

  if (authenticateClient(clientKey, signature)) {
    ...
    Ok(...)
  } else {
    Unauthorized(...)
  }
```

}

The problem arise when request is malformed and some headers are missing, then NoSuchElementException is thrown.

In imperative language, I would validate every step like this:

```
if (!request.headers.contains(AUTHORIZATION))
  return Unathorized

val authHeader = parseHeaders(request headers AUTHORIZATION)

if (!authHeader.contains("oauth_consumer_key") || !authHeader.contains("oauth_signature"))
  return Unathorized

val clientKey = authHeader("oauth_consumer_key")
val signature = authHeader("oauth_signature")

...
```

but what should I do to solve such problem in a functional way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `authHeader.get(key)` which returns an Option[B]. Your code then would look something like this:

```
val result = for {
  auth <- request.headers.get(AUTHORIZATION)
  authHeader = parseHeaders(auth)
  clientKey <- authHeader.get("oauth_consumer_key")
  signature <- authHeader.get("oauth_signature")
} yield { ... }

result.getOrElse(Unauthorized)
```

Explanation:

The whole expression will only be executed, if there is no `None` value. So if all headers are present you will get a `result` of `Some[A]` and if one or more are absent, you will get `None`. `result.getOrElse(Unauthorized)` will return the contained value for `Some[A]` and `Unauthorized` for `None`.